# How do I use a server for mobile application?

Tags: php, mobile, backend, haxe

I recently started to do development in the Haxe language with OpenFL (AS3 background).
But I have never worked on an app that communicates with a server - or never done any programming for servers for that matter!

I have to make a mobile app (for which I intend to use Haxe) where the new user creates an account on the server, and thus also interact withe other user accounts in a desired way.

So could someone guide me in the right direction to approach this situation? I'm guessing I will need to use PHP or ruby etc.
or can I use Haxe to program on the server? are there any good libraries that also provide security while making facility for user accounts? Is AWS or Google app engine something I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this simple but complete tutorial by filtreck
http://mromecki.fr/blog/post/haxite-writing-entire-website-using-haxe

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create normal web pages that you can host on the server which will retrieve the needed information.

After having uploaded these, use a type of webview in the application to load the pages and retrieve this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your server in Haxe if you want, and if you use a platform that supports it you could use TCP and haxe.remoting to pass data between the client and the server.

haxe.remoting is intended to make calling haxe function in a server from a client easier so that may be what you want.

If you don't feel confortable with using TCP you could do as Max wrote, just make some HTTP API (you can do this too in haxe) and do normal HTTP request from the client.